# Managing Magento csv Translation Files

Tags: module, magento-1, localisation

As time has passed, the Magento core team has added more and more default language packs to the

```
app/locale
```

folder.  Is there a canon way to manage your own translation files such that they don't interfere with future system upgrades?  i.e. I want to change some labels in Magento, so I edit

```
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Sales.csv
```

directly.  If we upgrade Magento, my changes will be wiped out.   Is the theme locale feature enough for this? (does it handle module specific files, or just `translate.csv`).  Or is it better to rewrite the translation models to load files from a different location?  Or something else?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Try this.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3259/make-magento-core-template-use-my-modules-translation-file/3284#3284)

To sum, specify an additional translation file under the core module's translation XPath and place your overriding CSV pairs in there.

```
<frontend>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <Mage_Sales>
                <files>
                    <mr_storms_wicked_translations>Mage_Sales_Custom.csv</mr_storms_wicked_translations>
                </files>
            </Mage_Sales>
        </modules>
    </translate>
</frontend>
```

Comment: You were too fast. I'm starting to lose it.

Answer (score 16):

Beside the `translate.csv` and the non-portable inline translate there is an other way. I do it like this.

Each module supports more than one translation file.

If you add this in `config.xml`:

```
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <[Namespace]_[Module]>
                <files>
                    <default>[Namespace]_[Module].csv</default>
                    <alternative>[Namespace]_[Module]_version2.csv</alternative>
                </files>
            </[Namespace]_[Module]>
        </modules>
    </translate>
```

both files `[Namespace]_[Module].csv` and `[Namespace]_[Module]_version2.csv` will be loaded for translation.

and they will be processed in the order in which they are declared.

So if you need for example to add/modify something in the `Mage_Sales.csv` don't edit the file just create a module that adds an other file to the translation files list.

Something like this:
`app/code/local/Easylife/Sales/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Sales>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Easylife_Sales>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Mage_Sales>
                    <files>
                        <alternative>Easylife_Sales.csv</alternative>
                    </files>
                </Mage_Sales>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
    <adminhtml>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Mage_Sales>
                    <files>
                        <alternative>Easylife_Sales.csv</alternative>
                    </files>
                </Mage_Sales>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

and make sure you make the module depend on `Mage_Sales`.
You can also create a "one size fits all" module for managing the translation. Just add an alternative translation file for any module you need and make sure this new module depends on all of them.

Comment: Will it just look at `app/locale/**/Easylife_Sales.csv` for this file? I assume that it will also allow subfolders as long as you know the directory separator for your filesystem?

Comment: I guess you can use subfolders if you want. I just never tried it.

Answer (score 9):

CSV files located in `app/locale` should be regarded as core files and not modified. I find that the best way to add custom translation is to put them into `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/locale/{locale}/translate.csv`

Please note that you can use module names in `translate.csv` files as well using `"Mage_Adminhtml::Sales","Sales"` instead of `"Sales","Sales"`. This also allows you to use translations that are custom tailored to specific themes.

Comment: The theme locale file is a good and fast way of doing things but what if you have multiple themes on the same instance?

Comment: I almost always prefer to use theme specific translations -- sometimes theme has less space and I need to use abbreviations instead. This also makes theme testing WAY simpler.

Comment: @Pronto I have done as you said but for some reason Magento will only load translate.csv if it is in `app/locale/`, how do I tell it to load it from `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/locale/` instead? See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554195/magento-translate-csv-file-not-loading

Answer (score 4):

You can edit/create the design/theme specific "translate.csv".
To override a translation from a "module-translation-file".
for example "Mage_Catalog.csv":

```
"Mage_Catalog::add to basket","into Basket"
```

So the Rule is "Module Namespace::string to be translated","translated string".
I think its the last Rule of the Magento translation Workflow.

Answer (score 1):

At SemExpert we do exactly that. We have our own es_AR translation package (with CSV files and email templates) and then all customizations are done either by translate.csv or by the inline translation feature (in very rare final-user cases).

We do not risk (for now) losing translation files due to Magento upgrading as it is very unlikely they will ever support es_AR out of the box, but we do suffer from Magento making small changes to their strings (like adding a '.' at the end of a sentence) that make english strings appear when you expect them the least.

I have started developing a small module to monitor translation strings which we use whenever a new Mage version is released. You can find it here: https://github.com/barbazul/SemExpert_TranslationDoctor