# Translate 'Subtotal' to 'Amount' in new order email in header row

Tags: magento-1.9, email-translation

How do i translate 'Subtotal' to 'Amount' in `new order email` in the *orange* header row? **Important:** a little below it has to stay 'Subtotal'.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know if you can translate it to a separate word without changing the original string in the template. If you want to just change the original string in the template, it is in `template/email/order/items.phtml`.

Comment: And do you know in which .csv files are the translations of the **order-email totals** and **invoice email-totals?** Thanks

Comment: @Meez - There’s a [few different ways you can create a new translation file](http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/30716/20131) with your new string in it.

Answer (score 0):

First, make a translation file. For example, for a Dutch translation, do this:

1. Make a folder called 'locale' in your theme folder.
2. In this folder, create another folder called 'nl_NL', where the first nl is the language, and the second NL the country. In this folder, create a file named 'translate.csv'.
3. Translate your string like this as an example: `"Subtotal","Subtotaal"`
4. If that doesn't work, you can translate more specific. In the url of the checkout, the first slug is `/checkout/`. So, translate like this: `"Mage_Checkout::Subtotal","Subtotaal"`.

An example of a translation file:

```
"male","Man"
"female","Vrouw"
"Print Order","Boeking printen"
"Artikel","Boeking"
"Product","Boeking"
"Item","Boeking"
"Item(s)","Boeking(en)"
"Items","Boekingen"
"Mage_Checkout::Artikel","Boeking"
"Mage_Checkout::Product","Boeking"
"Mage_Checkout::Item","Boeking"
"Mage_Checkout::Item(s)","Boeking(en)"
"Mage_Checkout::Items","Boekingen"
```

Hope this helps!